# How to detect physically single-orientation (non-rotating) Android device programmatically?

Tags: android, device, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait

We all know that Android was invented for handheld mobile devices but now there are lots of non-mobile devices you'd never dream of picking up and rotating such as TVs, and if I'm not mistaken even PCs (or things that closely resemble PCs) that run on Android.  For example the ViewSonic VSD231 looks to me like something you'd never pick up and rotate.

My Android app is only meant to run in portrait mode.  It programmatically locks the screen in portrait.  So if you open it up on a physically landscape-only device, you're looking at a sideways app with sideways writing.

Does Android yet have a way to detect physically single-orientation devices?  Or will it always be that users of such devices simply need to return apps they discover only work sideways on their device?  Seems like that could generate some bad reviews and should be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: I think you are talking about "natural orientation" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553650/how-to-check-device-natural-default-orientation-on-android-i-e-get-landscape

Comment: No I'm talking about a device's physical ability to be conveniently rotated, not just its default orientation.

Comment: Ok, now it is clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your manifest:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"
    android:required="true" />
```

Then the app will not appear in the Play Store for devices that do not support portrait orientation.  See the docs for [filters](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) and the [uses-feature](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) tag.

Comment: After reading the docs I learned that I was already in the clear since my <activity> element contains android:screenOrientation="portrait" which causes Google Play to exclude landscape-only devices, but the docs also add this: "As a best practice, you should still declare your requirement for this orientation using a <uses-feature> element."  (So I did.)