# Getting the natural orientation of a device in CN1

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

Is there a method to check the **natural** orientation of a device's screen **in Codename One**? Meaning, the default orientation regardless of the device's current rotation or current orientation. (e.g. the result should be on a galaxy tab: landscape, on a galaxy phone: portrait)

Note: Comparing getDisplayWidth/getDisplayHeight is not expedient!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a native API for getting the natural device orientation in any OS. Regardless, iOS only allows you to lock device orientation properly with a build hint so that wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: yes there is not a direct way to manage this, but this here works for me on android: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9888357/7449839

Comment: You can probably call that from a native interface