# Accelerometer x and y values are exchanged on smartphones and tablets

Tags: android, accelerometer

I use the accelerometer in my app and the activity is always in landscape mode. The x axis is used for speeding up (imagine something like a racing game) and the y axis is used to control direction left and right. Now I have the following problem:

On my smartphone in landscape mode the x axis is the shorter one and the y axis the longer one. The camera is positioned at the shorter side.

On my tablet the axis are vice versa. Also the camera is on the longer side. That means x axis is the shorter one (right / left) and y axis is the longer one (backward / forward). That means the user needs to tilt the tablet left and right for speeding and backwards and forwards for controlling direction. That is not what I want.

Can anyone tell me a way to find out if the axis are vice versa? I thought about detecting if we got a tablet or a smartphone but there are also tablets where the axis (and so the camera position also) are the same like on my smartphone.

Edit: I made a little picture with paint (I know I'm not a good painter^^). I hope you now understand my problem better. Top one is the smartphone, bottom one is the tablet - both in landscape mode. The circle is the camera which shows that the y-Axis is always where the camera is.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by getting the default device orientation and use it to determine if I need to use x or y for speed.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9888357/1794338 for getting the default device orientation