# App change portrait orientation to landscape on motorola xoom

Tags: android, orientation, landscape, portrait, xoom

We are developing an app, what is changing the hard coded orientation portrait to landscape on the 2nd launch.

We have screenOrientation="portrait" in all activity definitions in the manifest file.

Any idea how to resolve this? 
Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myproject"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="13"
    android:versionName="12.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@string/icon"
        android:label="@string/app"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.mobclix.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="XXXX" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".xyactivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".xyzActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".abactivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixBrowserActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you google at all ? Or for that matter search on SO before posting?

Comment: Yes, i googled it, if you know any solution just link it...

Comment: This is a specific problem what is appear only in motorola xoom...

Comment: Why dont u post code ? That may help..

Comment: There is my code (Manifest)

Comment: @ArnoldGergoHorvath: Eh, I think Siddharth meant your Java source codes. Without it, we can't see where you went wrong so we may not be able to help you.

Answer (score -1):

For restricting to only portrait orientation you need to put this code for every activity during declaration in your manifestfile

```
<activity android:name="MyApp" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

Comment: try  this site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674933/find-out-if-android-device-is-portrait-or-landscape-for-normal-usage
  
find-out-if-android-device-is-portrait-or-landscape-for-normal-usage to find whether the device is in landscape mode or portrait mode and then change the orientation to Portrait using this code

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);