# Why won't this code show Android device orientation changes?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

Last night, this code [(which I found here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674933/find-out-if-android-device-is-portrait-or-landscape-for-normal-usage) showed all kinds of `Log` output as I rotated my Android device, values from 0 to 360 and maybe some negatives.

But it doesn't work today. No `Log` output. I put a breakpoint on the `Log` statement; no stop when debugging.

I changed a few lines this morning to set a value based on value of `orientation` and then the problem (no output) surfaced, so I used `Show history` to revert back to the version of `MainActivity.java` that was last active last night. But no output and no stop at `Log` statement when debugging.

What explains this?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.OrientationEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    OrientationEventListener myOrientationEventListener ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
        {
            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) 
            {
                Log.w("Orient", orientation + "");
                myOrientationEventListener.enable();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

** EDIT **

As requested, here's `AndroidManifest.xml`, unchanged since 2/19, according to `Show history`, but I'll gladly add permission; but how did it work last night? [Also: Added line that stands out inside `<activity` as suggested in first Answer.]

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                package="com.dslomer64.nowweregettinsomewheres.fragments"
                android:versionCode="1"
                android:versionName="1.0" >

                <uses-sdk
                        android:minSdkVersion="11"
                        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

                <application
                        android:allowBackup="true"
                        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                        android:label="@string/app_name"
                        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                        <activity
                                   android:name="com.dslomer64.nowweregettinsomewheres.fragments.MainActivity"

android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

                                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                                <intent-filter>
                                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                                </intent-filter>
                        </activity>
                </application>

        </manifest>
```

Here's Android Studio 1.5.1 output:

```
            02-24 12:55:12.554 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 12:55:12.632 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 12:55:12.632 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 12:55:12.670 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 12:55:12.672 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 12:55:12.673 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 12:55:12.674 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 12:55:12.674 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 12:55:13.031 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 12:55:13.032 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 13:00:07.936 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/InputMethodManager: startInputInner : InputBindResult == null

            02-24 13:00:07.946 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 13:04:06.824 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 13:04:06.973 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 13:04:07.022 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 13:04:07.022 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 13:04:07.023 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 13:04:07.025 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 13:04:07.025 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 13:04:07.402 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection

            02-24 13:04:07.402 14836-14836/com.bffmedia.hour8app.intro W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Show your manifest. The activity needs to have permission to handle orientation changes

Comment: Actually I had a look at the other SO question. Maybe if you would try one of the upvoted answers, not the one that got 0 votes, it will work :)

Comment: How did it work last night??? I'm baffled. But I'll try one of the others.

Comment: Well I don't know what could changed since yesterday (your code? you tried on a different device? your manifest? your API level?, ... ) or maybe just the way you rotate the phone (fast/slow)? However I'm not even sure you need this sensor thing, every Activity is restarted when orientation changed, you should be able to detect it in onCreate()

Comment: @Gavriel--I took your advice and found a more reliable solution in my Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `Show history` doesn't necessarily include last change to code. Apparently, before rushing off to an appointment last night, I had moved the `.enable()` statement outside the `on` block. The code now works perfectly, as it did last night without change to `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
        myOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
        {
            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) 
            {
                ///////// NOT HERE myOrientationEventListener.enable(); //////////
                Log.w("Orient", orientation + "");
            }
        };
        Log.w("Listener", " can detect orientation: " + myOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation() + " " );

        myOrientationEventListener.enable(); // HERE ////////////////////////
```

I requested an edit of the Answer that the code came from to spare the next guy who uses it. That Answer is fine as long as the `enable` is placed logically.

*** HOWEVER (EDIT) ***

That listener doesn't quite work right anyway in my `onCreate` method. As suggested by @Gavriel, I found a better method:

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) ... do whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

You need configChanges="orientation" in your manifest.

Comment: I added that. Still no `Log` output.

Comment: What about `permission`?

Comment: well I don't know about this orientationchangelistener, but with the other solutions in the other question you don't need more than what I added here in my answer.