# know orientation of the phone in google Maps Android

Tags: android, gps, maps, orientation, compass

Im readig for the last two days and not sure about this,  would like to know if there is any way to read in my program (Android app) where the user is looking with the mobile (For example: User is looking to northeast with this degrees).

There is any API to do this or I have to program it with the compass and accelerometer of the mobile?

Edit:

What i want is this [blue dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ILSd.png) know where is pointing that triangular area.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out if Android device is portrait or landscape for normal usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674933/find-out-if-android-device-is-portrait-or-landscape-for-normal-usage)

Comment: The above duplicates link offers a number of methods to answer your question.  Please spend at least 5-10 minutes searching Stack Overflow and Google before you post something here.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I didnt explain myself good, I hope now with the picture is more clear